# Element not found exception is being raised in Python Selenium code

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I can't locate the element on the webpage. However, the element is on the webpage I could literally see it. I don't know what might be the problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time 

global browser 
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,5)
browser.get("https://www.rchermitage.org/donate.html")
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//.[@id="601882850817359718"]')))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

try:
 wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mc-page-wrapper"]/app-form/div/app-donation-widget/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/button/span[4]')))
print("Found")
except:
 print("Not Found")
```

I did try using explicit waits and Xpath to locate the element. But I couldn't find it. I did scroll into view of the element by using Xpath of the section of the element. I did try to locate different elements like radio button(Other Option), text box and clickable donate button but I couldn't interact with the section where are present in the webpage. What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the element section you are trying to access is part of an iframe
you need to switch to the frame in selenium before accessing it
[image]

Try below updated code and it should work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

global browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
browser.get("https://www.rchermitage.org/donate.html")
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="601882850817359718"]')))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

# Switch to Iframe
iframe = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src,'https://www.mightycause.com/forms/Congregation')]")
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)

try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                 '//*[@id="mc-page-wrapper"]/app-form/div/app-donation-widget/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/button/span[4]')))
    print("Found")
except:
    print("Not Found")
```

More on working with [IFrames](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/)